# Start a background service from outside the application

Tags: android, voip, background-service

I have created a VOIP application in android. It works fine. 
I have a written a service which always runs in background for checking the App incoming call. Its also works fine.

But, That background service stops after certain time. After that i wont receive any calls.

So, My questions are

1) How can i check that my service is running properly or not.

2) Also, If it is closed then how i again start it  ( Without starting the application ).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check why the service is stopped (it crashes probably?). It is not usual for services in Android to be stopped without them requesting so.

Comment: your service ... may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. -- Android docs.

Comment: Did you start it _sticky_? Did you start it in _foreground_?

Comment: Yes. Like Intent service = new Intent(this, serviceClass.class); startService(service);